# xelatex: -- produces hyphens instead of en-dash

Tags: xetex, punctuation

Using `xelatex`, the following code produces six hyphens, as in the code sample.
Using `pdflatex`, it produces a hyphen, an en-dash and an em-dash, as should be. The behavior is reproducible with other document classes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
- -- ---
\end{document}
```

This must have started more than a few days back (maybe weeks, maybe longer) but I only realized it today.
Is there an easy explanation for it?

I’m using Tex Live 2023 and it is up-to-date as per the Arch Linux repositories:

```
user@desktop ~ $ xelatex --version
XeTeX 3.141592653-2.6-0.999995 (TeX Live 2023/Arch Linux)
```

edit: As requested in the comments, I added `\XeTeXtracingfonts=1` before \documentclass, this is the log file:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999995 (TeX Live 2023/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=xelatex 2023.6.12)  4 AUG 2023 15:09
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**test.tex
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-02-22>
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
Requested font "[lmroman10-regular]:mapping=tex-text;" at 10.0pt
Font mapping `tex-text.tec' for font `[lmroman10-regular]:mapping=tex-text;' no
t found.
 -> /usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf
)
\c@part=\count181
\c@section=\count182
\c@subsection=\count183
\c@subsubsection=\count184
\c@paragraph=\count185
\c@subparagraph=\count186
\c@figure=\count187
\c@table=\count188
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\bibindent=\dimen140
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def
File: l3backend-xetex.def 2023-01-16 L3 backend support: XeTeX
\g__graphics_track_int=\count189
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box51
\g__pdf_backend_object_int=\count190
\g__pdf_backend_annotation_int=\count191
\g__pdf_backend_link_int=\count192
) (./test.aux)
\openout1 = `test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TS1+cmr on input line 3
.

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd
File: ts1cmr.fd 2022/07/10 v2.5l Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
 [1

] (./test.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 460 strings out of 476683
 9400 string characters out of 5809790
 1842018 words of memory out of 5000000
 20786 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 512295 words of font info for 33 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1348 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 33i,5n,38p,143b,107s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s

Output written on test.pdf (1 page).
```

Comment: well something disabled the ligatures. And `\XeTeXtracingfonts=1` before \documentclass and then show the log-file. (It works fine for me on windows)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Done, thank you for your time.

Comment: Your TeX installation is faulty, as witnessed by ``Font mapping `tex-text.tec' for font `[lmroman10-regular]:mapping=tex-text;' not found.``, which should be in `/usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/misc/xetex/fontmapping/base/`. Can you please look there to confirm the file is present?

Comment: If the file is present, then `sudo mktexlsr` should fix the issue.

Comment: @egreg There is no folder base in fontmapping. I have a lot of texlive packages installed, though. Should I list them?

Comment: @egreg But I just realized that the same behavior occurred in a file that I sent to a colleague a few days back. I compiled that on a different machine with a similar setup (up to date arch linux installation with tex live). If I somehow deleted relevant files / folders on the machine I’m currently working on, I couldn’t have done that on the other computer as well. Therefore I assume it must be an error in the Arch Linux repositories  (probably since they restructured Tex Live a few weeks back) or I lack relevant packages.

Comment: The answer in the question to which this one was marked a duplicate solved my issue.